# Checkbox changing database right away

Tags: php, javascript, database, checkbox

I got a problem with my Database and setting some info in it. I got a checkbox and when I click on it, I want it to change the value right away in the database when I click on the checkbox. I tried something with if(isset($_POST['showToilet']){} and then change it. It doesn't work because it probably has to reset the page.

A friend of mine said it's probably a javascript thing. Sadly I never worked with JS before.

So my question is: Can I set database info right away by just clicking on a checkbox?

Below you can find my code:

```
    <h2 align='center'>Toilet gegevens</h2>
    <?php



    $queryToilet = "SELECT * FROM toilet;";
    $resultToilet = mysql_query($queryToilet);

    echo "<table border ='1' align='center'>
        <tr bgcolor= 'grey'>
            <th>Show</th>
            <th>Toilet</th>
            <th>Art. nr.</th>
            <th>Art. nr fab.</th>
            <th>EAN nr.</th>
            <th>Closet</th>
            <th>Closet Afvoer</th>
            <th>Bevest schrf</th>
            <th>Reservoir</th>
            <th>Hoekstop kr</th>
            <th>Closet zitting</th>
            <th>Imagenaam</th>
            <th>Documentnaam</th>
            <th>Edit</th>   
        </tr>";

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultToilet))
        {
             echo "<tr bgcolor ='white'>";
             if($row2['Show'] == 1)
             {
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='showToilet' value='true'  checked/></td>";
             }
             else
             {
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='showToilet' value='true'/></td>";
             }

             if(isset($_POST['showToilet']))
             {
                $queryChangeShow = "Update toilet SET show ='" . $_POST['Show'] . "'";
             }
             echo "<td>" . $row2['Toilet'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['Artnr'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['ArtNrFabrikant'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['EANnr'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['Closet'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['ClosetAfvoer'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['Bevestigingsschroef'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['Reservoir'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['Hoekstopkraan'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['Closetzitting'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['ImagePath'] ."</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row2['DocumentPath'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td><a href=EditToilet.php?id=" . $row2['Artnr'] . ">edit</a></td>";
             echo "</tr>";
         }  
        echo "</table><br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Javascript, it is not possible to send a request to the server without reloading the page.

Using Javascript, you could make an [AJAX request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to the server, which could process the action immediately, and return information about the success or failure of the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Javascript using ajax requests or, if you want to make it easier, using jQuery ajax requests!

check [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. On clicking checkbox capture the variable you need to set.
2. Pass it as an data via Ajax Post
3. In processing page,which is another php page, get the data and
   change it in database using normal php queries.
4. Then send the necessary response to your main page.

Initially it takes time for you to understand the process. But it forms the basis for any AJAX based manipulations.

All the Best.